# What is an Emotional Word™?

Tags: word, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles[.](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=LszpV9WDKMyt8wf7rZKQBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=are+these+being+overdone%3F)</sub>

---

If a word has a certain property, I call it an Emotional Word™. If it definitively does not have that property, it is an Emotionless Word™.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Emotional Word™}&\textbf{Emotionless Word™}\\
\hline
\text{HOLIDAYS}&\text{VACATIONS}\\
\hline
\text{MEN}&\text{WOMEN}\\
\hline
\text{ MIXED*}&\text{JUMBLED}\\
\hline
\text{SACK}&\text{BAG}\\
\hline
\text{FAST}&\text{SPEEDY}\\
\hline
\text{BIRDS}&\text{AVIANS}\\
\hline
\text{HOUR}&\text{SECOND}\\
\hline
\text{TRIGGER}&\text{EXPLOSION}\\
\hline
\text{STRAIGHT}&\text{CURVED}\\
\hline
\text{STIFF}&\text{FIRM}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$$\text{* Meta-Emotional Word™.}$$

And a CSV version:

```
HOLIDAYS, VACATIONS
MEN, WOMEN
MIXED*, JUMBLED
SACK, BAG
FAST, SPEEDY
BIRDS, AVIANS
HOUR, SECOND
TRIGGER, EXPLOSION
STRAIGHT, CURVED
STIFF, FIRM
* Meta-Emotional Word™
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer could be:

> Each of the emotional words can be used with a feeling/ emotion.

Examples:

> Happy holidays! Trigger happy, Mixed feelings, Angry birds, Fast & Furious, Happy Hour.

## Max Li Edit

The full list of answers:

> Happy Holidays, Mad Men, Mixed Emotions, Sad Sack, Fast and Furious, Angry Birds, Happy Hour, Trigger Happy, Scared Straight, Scared Stiff.

Comment: +1 because this is probably the intended answer, but [minute should be an Emotional Word™](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_minute) if it is.

Comment: I was not aware of that and will edit the question. Thanks Will!